# How restore a postgres database with fig?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, docker, fig

I'm trying to use FIG (http://www.fig.sh/) for a django app. I can't recreate the database from a dump, I try:

```
fig run db pg_restore -d DBNAME < backup.sql
```

And get:

> socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

But this run (still not see the tables in the db):

```
fig run db pg_restore < backup.sql
```

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.4
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
ADD backup.sql /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pg_restore -d postgres  backup.sql
ADD . /code/
```

And fig.yml:

```
db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - 5432  
web:
  build: .
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
fig run db pg_restore -d DBNAME < backup.sql
```

postgresd is not running. You've replaced the startup of the daemon with the pg_restore command.

I would suggest doing something like this:

1. Move backup.sql to dockerfiles/db/backup.sql
2. Create a dockerfiles/db/Dockerfile
3. change your fig.yml to use build for the db instead

Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres
ADD . /files
WORKDIR /files
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start && \
    pg_restore -d DBNAME < backup.sql && \
    /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
```

fig.yml

```
db:
    build: dockerfiles/db
```

Now when you run any fig commands your database should be ready to go